# helix Perforce Unreal Engine file sharing issue

Tags: perforce

my friend and I are developing a game, and we're using Helix Perforce for file sharing. Unfortunately, we can't claim to be experts in Helix Perforce. Anyway, for the last 3 days, we've been struggling to share files. All the files inside the "Content" folder have yellow checkmarks and lock symbols on them. (I believe the files are locked, but we don't know how to unlock them.) My friend is experiencing the same issue. Could you please help us figure out how to solve this problem?[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aum6w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bkmA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZu6u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehwqh.png)

I reverted the files to their state from a few days ago in Helix Perforce, but the issue hasn't been resolved

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for certain just based on those screenshots, though it looks like you have lots of files marked for deletion, which probably isn't what you want.

I know there can be a bit of a learning curve with Helix Core so I've been making video content to help go over some of those basics.
Here is a beginner's guide playlist (not specific to Unreal) that would be a good place to start. [Helix Core Beginner's Guide](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH3pq2J85xsPYn71_yzzsZQKvalTW-duE)

And this is a video specifically about setting the server up for use with game engines like UE: [Configure Helix Core for Game Engines](https://youtu.be/Hvmvv2MG-UE)

Then this one covers using the Unreal Engine plugin: P[erforce Helix Core + Unreal Engine 5](https://youtu.be/7PRo8gK6SNM)

I know that's a lot of different resources but I really recommend taking the time to get familiar with how Helix Core works because it can really save you later on and help make sure you get the most out of your version control.